Evaluating $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin \frac{\theta}{x}}{-e^{-\theta x}}$ for $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$
Have been dealing with the L'Hospital rule for limits recently, with the $\frac{0}{0}$ case being touted as its canonical strength. So I began experimenting with simple functions that satisfy the $\frac{0}{0}$ case.
Consider the following: $\forall \,\theta \in (0, {\pi}/{2}) \text{ and real } x$:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin \frac{\theta}{x}}{-e^{-\theta x}}
$$
This is obviously a $\frac{0}{0}$ case. However, repeatedly taking derivatives of the numerator and denominator produces more of the same:
$$\lim_{ x\rightarrow \infty}\left(\sin \frac{\theta}{x}\right)' = -\theta \, x^{-2}\, \cos\frac{\theta}{x} = 0$$
and
$$\lim_{ x\rightarrow \infty}\left(-e^{-\theta x}\right)' = \theta \, e^{-\theta x} = 0
$$
If we continue with L'Hospital, the denominator is always going to have the exponential term $e^{-\theta x}$ and the numerator will have higher negative exponents on $x$.
Is there a simpler way to deal with this limit? I've a feeling I'm missing something fundamental here.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Numerator bounded, denominator goes to zero, so..

Hint: $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin{y}}{y} = 1$. Use this to change your numerator into a different form. Then rearrange the formula and apply the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ version of L'Hospital.

The fundamental thing you are missing is that L'Hôpital's rule is not a magic wand. It is but one of many tools for evaluating limits in indeterminate form.

If I expand the answer from Sine of the Time, I can write that:
$$
-\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sin(\theta/x)}{\theta/x} \frac{\theta}{x}e^{\theta x}
$$
$$
=-\theta\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sin(\theta/x)}{\theta/x}\right) \lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{e^{\theta x}}{x}\right)
$$
Now the first parenthesis is $1$ as a simple rule. For the second parenthesis, you can either apply L-Hopital or simply expand $e^{\theta x}$. If I consider the first rule, then:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{e^{\theta x}}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(xe^{\theta x}\right)=+\infty
$$
Therefore, the overall limit is:
$$\text{L}=-\infty$$
In case we had the limit $x\rightarrow -\infty$, then the overall limit would be $0$, since the second term $xe^{\theta x}$ would lead to $0$.

Hint:
$$-\lim_{x\to +\infty}\sin(\theta/x)e^{\theta x}=-\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\sin (\theta /x)}{\theta/x}\frac{\theta}xe^{\theta x} $$
